# How can I convert powerpoint into PDF that opens in fullscreen mode?

Tags: pdf, ms-office, powerpoint, acrobat

I know

- how to convert PPT to PDF
- how to make auto-fullscreen mode in Acrobat

But I would like to do it in PowerPoint itself. Where the PDF of the presentation I generate automatically opens in fullscreen mode in a PDF reader. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

They say the best quality you get when using the Acrobat PDFMaker macro for PowerPoint. This macro gets installed automagically when you install Acrobat (but, of course, not Reader).

In Acrobat (again not Reader), you set the opening properties for a document in the Initial View tab of the Document Properties (Ctrl-D / Cmd-D).

Comment: I don't get it. Are you saying if I install Acrobat PDFMaker, I can configure this option outside powerpoint for powerpoint to use?

Comment: I don't thinnk it's possible to do this directly from either PPT or via Acrobat's PDFMaker add-in.  It's possible to include an EPS with a bit of special PS code that tells Acrobat to open the file full page, then print to AdobePDF (or some others like GhostScript).  But in recent versions of PPT, you need to make a few registry tweaks to get this to work, otherwise PPT tries to interpret the EPS and convert it to EMF. So this can work on your own PC but it's not a solution that works well for distro.  I'm not at my work PC where I have the details but can answer later if you want more info.

Comment: @maximusdooku: Not being on Windows, I can't do a quick check what can be configured. But I have some doubts that it can. This means you have to set the switch to FullScreen in the Opening properties in the Document Properties dialog in Acrobat, as already mentioned. If you have to do this over and over again, you could also create an Action within Acrobat.